# how to use the variable of one class into another class using java?

Tags: java

Ihave two class files. In that first file, i stored aaa class firl and in the next text file i store the class file bbb.Io want to use the variable of aaa class into bbb class. How to use use it.

Note :If i put String value variable as public then it shows some error.

```
class aaa{
    public void method{
        String value="as some output";
        string other="it has some output";
    }
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    aaa obj=new first();
    bbb object=new second();
}

class bbb{
    aaa obj2=new aaa();
    System.out.println(obj2.value); //It gives error here also
}
```

Please suggest ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a Java tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing some basic knowledge of Java, maybe read up a few tutorials on the web.

```
// use capitals for the first letter, conventions are good ;)
public class Aaa{
    // I think this is what you meant, you want member variables, add public if you
    // want them to be accessible anywhere
    public String value="as some output";
    public String other="it has some output";

    // missing brackets
    public void method() {
        // do something/anything
    }
}

public class Bbb{
    // you need to put this in a main... without getting exceptions
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Aaa obj2=new Aaa();
        // now you can access the field value, since it's public
        System.out.println(obj2.value); //error should be gone now
    }
}

public class TestMain{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        // first and second aren't classes, you meant Aaa and Bbb?
        Aaa objA=new Aaa();
        Bbb objB=new Bbb();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class aaa does not have a public member variable that is called value.
You have a local variable value in your method, which you will not be able to use.

There are mainly two options:

a) Use a getter method.

```
class Aaa
{
    //...
    public String getValue()
    {
        return this value;
    }
}

//...
Aaa a = new Aaa();
String test = a.getValue();
//...
```

b) Use a public member variable.

```
class Foo
{
   // ...
   public String value = "bar"; 
   //...
}

//...
Aaa a = new Aaa();
String test = a.value;
//...
```

I recommend you use the first one.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, value is a local variable within the `Bbb.method` method. To access it from another class, it must be an *instance* variable of the class (declared in the class but outside any method) and accessible (public, or package (aka default), or private with getter/setter methods)

```
// note that I've renamed classes to follow the convention of uppercasing class names.
// this makes the code much easier to read.
class Aaa {
    public String value = "instance value initialized when the class loads (first use)";
    public String other = null;

    // a method declaration must have parentheses, even if it takes no parameters
    public void method() {
        other = "instance value, initially null, set by calling method";
    }
}

class Bbb {
    Aaa aaaInBbb = new Aaa();

    public void method(){
        // every statement (except variable declarations) must be in a method
        System.out.println(aaaInBbb.value); // access the public value in aaaInBbb
    }
}

class C {
    // note that main(...) must be in a class as well - as all methods in Java must
    public static void main(String[] args) { // convention also puts [] next to the type
        Aaa aaa = new Aaa(); // this variable is never used.
        Bbb bbb = new Bbb();

        bbb.method();  // causes instance of Bbb to print out aaaInBbb.value
    }
}
```

I've added some additional comments on syntax and standard code conventions that will help you as you learn Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple declare the variable and initialize the value of variable in method1 and finally extends that class.

```
class aaa{
String value;
    public void method(){
         value="as some output";       
    }
}

class bbb extends aaa{  
     public void method2(){
         System.out.println(value); //Output is "as some output";      
    }      

    public static void main(String as[]){
     bbb obj2=new bbb();
     obj2.method();   //getting the value of string value
     obj2.method2(); //print the value in method2
     }
}
```